# What am I doing wrong in this Microblaze assembly bubble sort?

Tags: assembly, bubble-sort, microblaze

I am working on a program for a Basys 3 Microblaze in its assembly language. However, the language is quite different from anything I can find online. [I have documentation for it here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AOMlAbxcjW37Ab03E2Cf-KPE3etORm57/view?usp=share_link), with the assembly commands available to me starting in chapter 4 (page 65).

The code I have takes 10 characters input from the terminal, and after each input it checks the switches on the Basys and changes the 7-segment displays. But I'm not worried about that. The part I am having trouble with is that these 10 single character inputs are stored in an array. I need to go through and bubble sort this array of characters and then spit them back out again. I have a sort function that is supposed to do this but I just cannot get it to work. If anyone can please help me figure out what I am doing wrong, I will be grateful. I have been up all night trying to figure this out. I use the Xilinx SDK from Vivado 2019.1 (and below as the SDK was removed in 2019.2).
Here is my code:

```
    #Equates
.set NUMLOOPS, 10
.set SWITCH_DATA, 0x40000000
.set SEV_SEG_DATA, 0x40010000
.set UART, 0x40600000


#Memory Section
$msgBegin:
    .asciz "\r\n Program Start.\r\n"
    .text
    .align 2
$msgWithChar:
    .asciz  "Character %d - %c\r\n"
    .text
    .align  2
$Nums:
    .fill 10, 4, 65
    .data
    .align 4
$msgLoop:
    .asciz "\r\n Embedded Systems Loop #%2d.\r\n"
    .text
    .align 2
$msgEnd:
    .asciz "\r\n Program Stop.\r\n"
    .text
    .align 2
$msgTest1:
    .asciz "\r\n Test 1."
    .text
    .align 2
$msgTest2:
    .asciz "\r\n Test 2."
    .text
    .align 2
$msgTest3:
    .asciz "\r\n Test 3."
    .text
    .align 2
$msgSpace:
    .asciz "\r\n"
    .text
    .align 2

#Main Program
.globl  main
main:
    addi  r5, r0, $msgBegin # Store string to print
    addi  r1, r1, -4        # Push r15 onto stack
    swi   r15,r1, 0
    brlid r15,xil_printf    # Call print func; retn addr in r15
    nop                     # Unfilled delay slot
    lwi   r15,r1, 0         # Pop r15 off the stack
    addi  r1, r1, 4
    addi  r19, r0, NUMLOOPS # Initialize R19 to NUMLOOPS
    addi  r20, r0, 1        # Initialize R20 to one
    addi  r22, r0, 0        # Initialize R22 to 0
.globl  loop
loop:
    beqi  r19, sort         # If R19==0, branch to done; stop program
    nop
    rsub  r19,r20,r19       # Decrement loop counter (R19) by 1 (R20)
    lwi   r11, r0, SWITCH_DATA  # Read data from switches
    swi   r11, r0, SEV_SEG_DATA # Write switch data to 7-segment disp
    addi  r5, r0, UART      # Set R5 arg to UART memory address
    addi  r1, r1, -4        # Push r15 onto stack
    swi   r15, r1, 0
    brlid r15, XUartLite_RecvByte # Call UART Receive function
    nop
    lwi   r15, r1, 0        # Pop r15 off stack
    addi  r1, r1, 4
    swi   r3, r22, $Nums    # Store value into $Nums array at offset R22
    add   r6, r0, r3        # Move char R3 into R6 to display to UART
    addi  r1, r1, -4        # Push r15 on stack
    swi   r15, r1, 0
    brlid r15, XUartLite_SendByte # Call Uart Send function
    nop
    lwi   r15, r1, 0        # Pop r15 off stack
    addi  r1, r1, 4
    addi  r22, r22, 4       # Increment R22 by 4 bytes
    bri   loop
    nop

.globl sort
sort:
    addi r23, r0, 10        # Initialize R23 for outer loop counter
    addi r24, r0, 10        # Initialize R24 for inner loop counter
    addi r22, r0, 0         # Reinitialize R22 to zero
    addi r29, r0, 0         # Initialize R29 for address offset of a[0]

for1:
    #Print Test
    addi  r5, r0, $msgTest1 # Store string to print
    addi  r1, r1, -4        # Push r15 onto stack
    swi   r15,r1, 0
    brlid r15,xil_printf    # Call print func; retn addr in r15
    nop                     # Unfilled delay slot
    lwi   r15,r1, 0         # Pop r15 off the stack
    addi  r1, r1, 4


    beqid r23, disp            # If R23==0, branch to disp
    nop
    addi r23, r23, -1          # Decrement outer loop counter (R23) by 1
    addi r24, r0, 10   # Initialize R24 for inner loop counter
    addi r24, r24, -1           # Subtract 1 from R24 (since we are comparing i and i+1)

for2:
    #Print Test
    addi  r5, r0, $msgTest2 # Store string to print
    addi  r1, r1, -4        # Push r15 onto stack
    swi   r15,r1, 0
    brlid r15,xil_printf    # Call print func; retn addr in r15
    nop                     # Unfilled delay slot
    lwi   r15,r1, 0         # Pop r15 off the stack
    addi  r1, r1, 4


    beqid r24, for1            # If R24==0, branch to for1
    nop
    addi r24, r24, -1          # Decrement inner loop counter (R24) by 1
    addi r25, r0, 0            # Initialize R25 for address offset of a[i]
    muli r25, r24, 4 # Calculate address offset for a[i]
    lwi r26, r25, $Nums        # Load a[i] into R26
    addi r25, r25, 4 # Increment R25 for address offset of a[i+1]
    lwi r27, r25, $Nums        # Load a[i+1] into R27

    addi r28, r0, 0
    cmp r28, r26, r27
    bgtid r28, for2       # If a[i] > a[i+1], skip the swap
    nop


swap:
    #Print Test
    addi  r5, r0, $msgTest3 # Store string to print
    addi  r1, r1, -4        # Push r15 onto stack
    swi   r15,r1, 0
    brlid r15,xil_printf    # Call print func; retn addr in r15
    nop                     # Unfilled delay slot
    lwi   r15,r1, 0         # Pop r15 off the stack
    addi  r1, r1, 4


    swi r26, r25, $Nums        # Store R26 (a[i]) into a[i+1] location
    swi r27, r25, $Nums        # Store R27 (a[i+1]) into a[i] location (using R25 - ARRAY_OFFSET)
    rsubi r25, r25, -4
    bri for2
    nop



.globl  disp
disp:
    addi  r19, r0, NUMLOOPS # Reinitialize R19 to NUMLOOPS
    addi  r22, r0, 0        # Reinitialize R22 to zero
    addi  r5, r0, $msgSpace # 1st arg R5 is format string
    add   r6, r0, r22       # 2nd arg R6 is address offset
    lwi   r7, r22, $Nums    # 3rd arg R7 is array value at this offset
    addi  r1, r1, -4        # Push r15 on stack
    swi   r15, r1, 0
    brlid r15, xil_printf   # Call printf
    nop
    lwi   r15, r1, 0        # Pop r15 off stack
    addi  r1, r1, 4
.globl loop2
loop2:
    beqi  r19, done         # If R19==0, branch to done; stop program
    nop
    rsub  r19,r20,r19       # Decrement loop counter (R19) by 1 (R20)
    addi  r5, r0, $msgWithChar # 1st arg R5 is format string
    add   r6, r0, r22       # 2nd arg R6 is address offset
    lwi   r7, r22, $Nums    # 3rd arg R7 is array value at this offset
    addi  r1, r1, -4        # Push r15 on stack
    swi   r15, r1, 0
    brlid r15, xil_printf   # Call printf
    nop
    lwi   r15, r1, 0        # Pop r15 off stack
    addi  r1, r1, 4
    addi  r22, r22, 4       # Increment R22 by 4 bytes
    bri   loop2
.globl  done
done:
    addi  r5, r0, $msgEnd   # Store string to print
    addi  r1, r1, -4        # Push r15 onto stack
    swi   r15,r1, 0
    brlid r15,xil_printf    # Call print func; retn addr in r15
    nop                     # Unfilled delay slot
    lwi   r15,r1, 0         # Pop r15 off the stack
    addi  r1, r1, 4
```

Comment: A [mcve] should include details of what goes wrong, the actual result for a certain input.  And/or some debugging details you see from single-stepping with a debugger, like a branch that's not-taken when you expected it to be taken.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> beqi  r19, sort         # If R19==0, branch to done; stop program
> ```

Should become `beqi r19, done`

---

> ```
> swi r26, r25, $Nums        # Store R26 (a[i]) into a[i+1] location
> swi r27, r25, $Nums        # Store R27 (a[i+1]) into a[i] location (using R25 - ARRAY_OFFSET)
> rsubi r25, r25, -4
> bri for2
> nop
> ```

**You are not swapping the values**. Both stores go to the same address.

```
swi r26, r25, $Nums        # Store R26 (a[i]) into a[i+1] location
addi r25, r25, -4
swi r27, r25, $Nums        # Store R27 (a[i+1]) into a[i] location
bri for2
nop
```

---

Currently your code is processing *all* the array elements for *every* iteration of the outer loop. In BubbleSort you are supposed to reduce the array by 1 element on every iteration of the outer loop. The max/min (depending ascending/descending) will have moved ('bubbled') to an extremity and you should no longer have to deal with it.
Because you bubble towards the *beginning* of the array (how odd...) it would be that first element that you would no longer need to consider as soon as the inner loop has run once.

---

It will be easier to write the correct code if you remove:

- those temporary outputs that you wrote for verification purposes only
- instructions that are redundant like setting up R22 and R29 that remain unused

---

### A possible solution

```
.globl sort
sort:
    addi r23, r0, 9     # Initialize R23 for outer loop counter
for1:
    beqid r23, disp     # If R23==0, branch to disp
    nop
    addi r24, r23, 0    # Initialize R24 for inner loop counter (ever smaller)
    addi r23, r23, -1   # Decrement outer loop counter (R23) by 1
    addi r25, r0, -4    # Initialize R25 for address offset of a[i]
for2:
    beqid r24, for1     # If R24==0, branch to for1
    nop
    addi r24, r24, -1   # Decrement inner loop counter (R24) by 1
    addi r25, r25, 4    # Calculate address offset for a[i]
    addi r26, r25, 4    # Calculate address offset for a[i+1]

    lwi r27, r25, $Nums # Load a[i] into R27
    lwi r28, r26, $Nums # Load a[i+1] into R28

    addi r29, r0, 0
    cmp r29, r27, r28
    bgtid r29, for2     # If a[i] > a[i+1], skip the swap
    nop
swap:
    swi r27, r26, $Nums # Store R27 (a[i]) into a[i+1]
    swi r28, r25, $Nums # Store R28 (a[i+1]) into a[i]
    bri for2
    nop

.globl  disp
disp:
```